# Dragon Fruit developing translucent areas which then turn tan/white

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, diseases, discoloration

I have two dragon fruit plants which were started from healthy cuttings.  The new growth segments have developed an odd thing which I can't figure out when reading up on problems and diseases.  Along the edges, areas will thin out and be translucent green.  Within approximately a week, those areas will leave behind tan/white dried up, paper-thin regions.

Would love help identifying what's going on.  And obviously beyond that, how to treat it, how to prevent it.  You know, who wouldn't want a healthy dragon fruit plant?

Area is Central Florida, far as sun and climate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some pictures, details about the soil, watering schedule, sunlight it receives etc.?

Comment: just attached 2 pictures.  water twice a week.  area is full sun ~70% of the day.  soil is a mix of the area's sandy soil, plus compost we make from our food waste, some worm poop added as well.

Comment: one other note, the new growth from original cuttings is growing very rapidly, so aside from these spots, it's seems to be happily growing.